# Sitecore AD configuration of component 1.3 without domain name Login

Tags: sitecore-client, multisite, sitecore-query

I have integrated with Active Directory 1.3 and Login is happening perfectly fine with with the username as domain\username and password.

My requirement is to just sign in  without with domain. For example: I should be able to login to sitecore using username and password without adding the domain.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please give examples of how you have setup your integration and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I believe if you are using the switching provider then this only works for the "sitecore" domain. May also have to do with the order listed in the config.